# Odoo 13 : How to write a good filters in order to sent data to odoo website page?

Tags: python, odoo

I've been asked to do some filters before passing the data to the website.
I have four(4) models that are linked with many2many fields. Let me add an image of the four models.[image]

In order to print the model.a, we need to check if it has model.b linked to it, then check if some model.c is linked to model.b and finally, check if some model.d is linked to model.c. After all of that. The result is the same as this image [image]
To do that, I wrote this code :

```
@http.route(['/agenda'], auth="public", website=True)
def agenda(self):
    months = DATES_SELECT
    # all dictionary used in the implementation
    model_c_dict = {}
    model_b_dict = {}
    model_a_dict = {}
    model_a_key = []
    # filter the model.d according to certain condition
    # should I set registrations_left field as store=True for performance when using .search()
    model_d_ids = request.env['model.d'].search([('date_start', '>', dt.now().date()), ('state', '=', 'opened')], order="date_start").filtered(lambda k: k.registrations_left != 0)
    for session in model_d_ids:
        course_id = session.course_id_many[:1]
        if not course_id.state == 'validated':
            continue
        model_c_dict.setdefault(course_id.id, {'object': course_id, 'sessions': []})
        model_c_dict[course_id.id]['sessions'].append(session)
    for k, v in model_c_dict.items():
        category_id = v['object'].category_ids[:1]
        if not category_id:
            continue
        model_b_dict.setdefault(category_id.id, {'object': category_id, 'course': {}})
        model_b_dict[category_id.id]['course'].setdefault(k, v)
    for k, v in model_b_dict.items():
        catalogue_id = v['object'].catalogue_ids[:1]
        if not catalogue_id:
            continue
        model_a_dict.setdefault(catalogue_id.id, {'object': catalogue_id, 'category':  {}})
        model_a_dict[catalogue_id.id]['category'].setdefault(k, v)
        if catalogue_id.id in model_a_dict:
            model_a_key.append(catalogue_id)
    # sort the model_a with model_a.sequence as key
    model_a_key = sorted(list(set(model_a_key)), key=lambda k: k.sequence)

    # pack key
    dict_key = {'model_a_key': model_a_key}

    values = {
        'months': months,
        'categs': model_a_dict,
        'dict_key': dict_key,
    }

    return request.render('website_custom.agenda', values)
```

It works as intended, but I don't know if It has performance issues, if it's bad coding, ...
So I'm asking your opinion.
PS: I didn't design the models and its relations.

Comment: Are you sure you tested your code with very complicated structure, because I can see that you always treat only the first record from the many2many field, Do you want to retreive all A model that are connected all the way down to D model. I think your code can miss some records.

Comment: If there was many2many field in the other direction this will make the code more simpler and easier, and faster and you don't have to loop three time like this.

Comment: @CharifDZ, I want to treat the first record because the many2many should be one2many. I hope you understand what I mean

Comment: It will understand if you said It should be many2one, but one2many contains more than one record too, I don't know but if this what you need just remove the loops in my code and replace them with a simple assignment like I showed in the comment, i'm using my phone now but the code should do the same as your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I loved the slice technique to avoid `index out of range error`, and can be very usefull to check if the record is connected
all the way up to A (catalogue model) in filtered function `k.course_id_many[:1].category_ids[:1].catalogue_ids[:1]` but I prefer doing this in the domain:

```py
@http.route(['/agenda'], auth="public", website=True)
def agenda(self):
    courses_dict = {}
    category_dict = {}
    catalogue_dict = {}
    # extract all record of Model D connected all the way up to A model
    sessions = request.env['model.d'].search([('date_start', '>', dt.now().date()),
                                              ('state', '=', 'opened'),
                                              # this will make sure that the record retrieved will be connected to catalogue model (A)
                                              ('course_id_many.category_ids.catalogue_ids', '!=', False)], order="date_start") \
        .filtered(lambda k: k.registrations_left != 0)

    for session in sessions:
        # if you want to treat olny the first record you can add the slice on the many2many [:1]
        # but I think you will skip the rest of the record in the many2many field
        # and if this what you want the loop are not needed at all just do `course = session.course_id_many[0]`
        # and do the same for all loops. because you don't have to check if the record are connected we all ready did that in search method
        course = session.course_id_many[0]
        if not course.state == 'validated': continue  # skip validated courses

        # add course to dict, and add the session to it's list of sessions
        course_obj = courses_dict.setdefault(course.id, {'object': course, 'sessions': []})
        course_obj['sessions'].append(session)

        category = course.category_ids[0]
        # store category, and add course to it's list of courses
        category_obj = category_dict.setdefault(category.id, {'object': category, 'course': {}})
        category_obj = category_dict[category.id]['course'][course.id] = course_obj

        catalogue = category.catalogue_ids[0]
        # sotre catalog, and add category to it's categories list
        catalogue_dict.setdefault(catalogue.id, {'object': catalogue, 'category': {}})['category'][category.id] = category_obj

    # sort catalogue
    catalogue_keys = sorted(catalogue_dict.keys(), key=lambda k: catalogue_dict[k]['object'].sequence)

    values = {
        'months': DATES_SELECT,
        'categs': catalogue_dict,
        'dict_key': catalogue_keys,
    }

    return request.render('website_custom.agenda', values)
```

I hope this work I did the best to check for syntax errors, It should work.

Comment: Thank you very much for your code. I will test it and will give you a feedback

Comment: I picked some lines of your code. Now, rendering template improves 23ms to 13ms

Comment: @m0r7y with little adjustment I think it's easier to read, because we don't need to loop over one record. I hope this helps you